# Why fread() returns 0?

Tags: c, fread

I don't udnerstand that.
The File exists. It has contant which length is fitting the value hold by `sizeIndexI`.
I'm at the begining of the File(Am I not?) and anyway It wont read from that file...

Ofc. the file also was succesfully opened before. (In this case with `a+`) And the access permissions for the File are ofc. also given.

```
fpNewsPageLogger = fopen ("/NewsLogx", "a+");

if (fpNewsPageLogger == nullptr)
{
            /*...*/
}
else
{
        fseek (fpNewsPageLogger, 0 ,SEEK_END);
        sizeIndexI = ftell (fpNewsPageLogger);
        rewind (fpNewsPageLogger);
        DebugLogMsg10 (pDebugLogger, sizeThreadID, "ReadAmount:%d IndexI:%d!", sizeBytesRead, sizeIndexI);

        cpTmpNews = calloc (sizeIndexI, sizeof(char));

        if (cpTmpNews == nullptr)
        {
            fclose (fpNewsPageLogger);
            return;
        }

        sizeBytesRead = fread (cpTmpNews, sizeof (char), sizeIndexI, fpNewsPageLogger);

    /*...*/
}
```

Is there anything I'm not thinking about?

Comment: About what type & value is `sizeIndexI`?  a+ does a "append; open or create text file for update, writing at end-of-file".  Does that affect `ftell (fpNewsPageLogger)`?

Comment: Are you checking the results of `calloc()`, `fseek()`, `ftell()`?

Comment: Post the code you're using to open the file.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Why you ask me for checking results, you can see in my code that I do....

Comment: @chux its of type size_t and its value is 291. and I couldn't find anything that would say it would affect it.

Comment: BTW, `sizeof (char)` is always 1.

Comment: @glglgl: That does not necessarily mean that using `sizeof(char)` in the code is somehow wrong.

Comment: @AndreyT No, that's why I put it as BTW and not as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, standard library is not required to meaningfully support seeking from `SEEK_END`. Did you check the value of `sizeIndexI`? Maybe it is simply zero? If you ask `fread` to read zero elements, it expectedly returns zero.

Secondly, you are opening your stream as a text stream. For a text stream values returned by `ftell` do not generally have any meaningful numerical semantics. In general case `ftell` for text streams returns an implementation defined encoding of the current position, not the byte offset from the beginning of the file. If you want to work with your stream as binary stream, add "b" to `fopen`

```
fpNewsPageLogger = fopen ("/NewsLogx", "ab+");
```

Comment: You can see in code that I'm checking and in comments I also answered it.

Comment: OK. But I don't see you checking it in your code. Where?

Comment: I check it out about an own debug system. If I would post that code it wouldnt help you anyway wihtout knowing my debug app. So just belive me plz, ftell returns the expected amount.

Comment: @Zaibis: So, did the value returned by `ftell` match the actual size of the file? And, again, I don't see where you check the value of `sizeIndexI` in your code. I hope you are aware of the fact that `calloc(0)` so not required to return null pointer.

Comment: @Zaibis believe me, your magical debugging app will not help us. You should either make code which checks `ftell` returned value or give us any information about your debug app.

Comment: The point is, the line is just somehow like `DebugLVLX ("%d", sizeIndexI)` and I told already the result. As In the OP I allready wrote, the returning value matches the files size.

Comment: I eddited that line in for you.